# Saving a .txt file in a different directory than the original python3

Tags: python

I am trying to save a file that my program creates a directory that is within the directory the program is run in.

Basically my it looks like this:

```
DIRECTORY_ONE:
     program.py
     DIRECTORY_TWO:
```

So I want program.py to save to DIRECTORY_TWO

I've tried

```
outFile = open("/output_DB/" + "out.txt",'w')
```

and making into a with ... as block among a few other methods

What is the best way to do this task?

Comment: Whilst the methods in the answers below are all good, I feel it's worth pointing out that the only reason your code doesn't work is because of the leading forward slash before your directory name, so it becomes an absolute path rather than a relative one. Changing it to either `"./output_DB/"` or `"output_DB/"` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if directory exists. If not, create it.

```
if not os.path.exists("output_DB"):
    os.makedirs("output_DB")

outFile = open("output_DB/" + "out.txt",'w')
```